# How to filter on mdx dimension

Tags: mdx

I have a query which i want to filter it on max of one of its dimension fields like this:

```
SELECT
    {
    [Measures].[F Sra Quantity],
    [Measures].[F Sra Gross],
    [Measures].[F Sra Disc TOTAL]
    } 

DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME 
ON COLUMNS, 

NON EMPTY

CrossJoin( 
        {[Branch Dim].[b Name].Children},
        {[Date Dim].[d Year Month].Children},
        {[Date Dim].[Full Date].Children},
        {[Customer Dim].[c Name].Children},
        {[Customer Dim].[c Path].Children},
        {[Order Specification Dim].[Os Type No].Children},
        {[Sales Team Dim].[Id].Children},
        {[Sales Team Dim].[St Visitor].Children}
        )

ON ROWS 

FROM [D Sys Warehouse]
```

I want to filter it on the max value of [Os Type No] which its members are changing always. would you help me please?

Comment: Do you mean that you only want to have the maximum value of `[Os Type No]` in the output?

Comment: yes, of course  [Os Type No] with a not null value for all three measures.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested as I'm not near `SSAS` or the `AdvWrks` cube but something along these lines might work, assuming I have interpreted your request correctly:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[MAX_No] AS
  MAX(
    [Order Specification Dim].[Os Type No].MEMBERS,
    [Order Specification Dim].[Os Type No].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_VALUE
  )
SELECT
    {
    [Measures].[F Sra Quantity],
    [Measures].[F Sra Gross],
    [Measures].[F Sra Disc TOTAL]
    } 

DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME 
ON COLUMNS, 

NON EMPTY

CrossJoin( 
        {[Branch Dim].[b Name].Children},
        {[Date Dim].[d Year Month].Children},
        {[Date Dim].[Full Date].Children},
        {[Customer Dim].[c Name].Children},
        {[Customer Dim].[c Path].Children},
        {[Order Specification Dim].[Os Type No].Children},
        {[Sales Team Dim].[Id].Children},
        {[Sales Team Dim].[St Visitor].Children}
        )
HAVING 
  [Order Specification Dim].[Os Type No].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_VALUE = [Measures].[MAX_No]
ON ROWS 

FROM [D Sys Warehouse]
```